# AngularJs $interval on service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm a beginner in `Angularjs` and so I would like ask you if there is a better way for solve my issue.

I need to update, for example, every 30 seconds the content of a `<div>` with an ajax call.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>{{test.value}}</div>
</div>
```

My idea was use `$interval` on a `service` as following:

```
.service('eedisplayService', function($q, $http, $interval){
    this.getData = function(url, variable){
        $interval(function (){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
             $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data){
                if (data){
                    variable.value = data
                } else {
                    deferred.reject('Wrong response');
                }
            })
            .error(function(){
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise
        },30000);
    }

});
```

And call service from `controller` like this:

```
.controller('displayCtrl', function($scope, config, eedisplayService){

    var url = "myUrl";

    $scope.test = {value : "" };

    eedisplayService.getData(url, $scope.test);

});
```

Is it a fully AngularJs approach? The code works, but is a good choice call a service with an `$interval` from controller? Is not better call it from `config` for example?

I checked out a lot of examples, but I don't really understand what is the best way to do this.

Thanks so much.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could think about putting the `$interval` functionality in your controller so your service could be more generic/reusable.

Also `$http` returns a promise on it's own so you don't necessarily need to do that manually:

```
// your service 
.service('eedisplayService', function($http){
  this.getData = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url);
  }
}); 


// controller 
...
$interval(function() {
  eedisplayService.getData(...)
  .then(function(response) {
    // update the content in the view 
  })
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!